# Is it possible to talk to bitcoin RPC API with Javascript and WITHOUT using a node server?

Tags: javascript

I am planning on building a Wallet and want to know if I can hook something like an Electron native JavaScript app to Bitcoin RPC without running node.js for the server calls, so using something like AJAX or XMLhttprequest.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible? Yes definitely!

Is it secure and smart to do? NO!

Anyone can see the password of your bitcoin node and thus steal your funds.

You will be hacked in no time.